# How can I show correct 4 thumbnails in 1 row using foreach

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor, thumbnails

In result I have next view:

[image]

### view.cshtml

```
<div class="row">
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="@Url.Content(item.Photo ?? "~/Content/noimg.png")" class="img-thumbnail" alt="@item.Name" />
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>@item.Name</h3>
                <p class="text-center">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Изменить", "Edit", new {id = item.GameId}, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-xs" })
                    @Html.ActionLink("Детали", "Details", new {id = item.GameId}, new { @class = "btn btn-info btn-xs" })
                    @Html.ActionLink("Удалить", "Delete", new {id = item.GameId}, new { @class = "btn btn-danger btn-xs" })
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

What should I change in styles to correctly display **4 images (and the name of the game too)**

Default class .thumbnail

```
    .thumbnail {
    display: block;
    padding: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    background-color: #002b36;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-transition: border 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: border 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: border 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.thumbnail > img,
.thumbnail a > img {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
a.thumbnail:hover,
a.thumbnail:focus,
a.thumbnail.active {
    border-color: #2aa198;
}
.thumbnail .caption {
    padding: 9px;
    color: #839496;
}
```

So what I need change?
Please help me.

result without "caption"
[image]

Comment: can you share the styling for .thumbnail class, looks like it's causing the issue as height is not same for all blocks

Comment: bootstrap.css or bootstrap.min.css?

Comment: The height is not the same because of the different length of `h3` text in the `caption` div. You should post the minimum CSS code that you can, do not post your whole CSS file

Comment: This will happen if all your Bootstrap `col-`'s are different heights and you are putting more than 12 columns in a `.row`. One of this easiest ways I solve this is to use a plugin called [matchHeights](https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height)

Answer (score 1):

First of all create a good 'ol table... Secondo create a variable counter. Tersio, check the exemple below...

```
var counter = 1;
<table>
<tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {       
        <td style="border:1px solid black; vertical-align:text-bottom">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
         <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="@Url.Content(item.Photo ?? "~/Content/noimg.png")" class="img-thumbnail" alt="@item.Name" />
           <div class="caption">
            <h3>@item.Name</h3>
            <p class="text-center">
                @Html.ActionLink("Изменить", "Edit", new {id = item.GameId}, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-xs" })
                @Html.ActionLink("Детали", "Details", new {id = item.GameId}, new { @class = "btn btn-info btn-xs" })
                @Html.ActionLink("Удалить", "Delete", new {id = item.GameId}, new { @class = "btn btn-danger btn-xs" })
            </p>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        </td>
        if(counter%4 == 0)
         {
             @:</tr><tr>
         }
        counter++;
    }      
}
</table>
```

Each time it will get the number of value in the row you want (exemple=4  if(counter%4 == 0) ) than it will trigger the end of that row...

I think it's a different way of doing exactly what you need...

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the CSS code for .thumbnail class, it seems clear that the difference in heights occurs because of absence of height property on this css class. Add *height* property to thumbnail class and it should work fine.

EDIT #1 - after comment from zgood
inner elements will not automatically scale so you need to add height to img as well, also based on your requirements you have to handle overflow for the text content

sample code - set it to a height which seems suitable in your case

```
.thumbnail{
    height: 100px;
    // code removed for brewity
}
.thumbnail > img{
    height: 100px;
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Couldn't content still overflow (like the caption or the `img` possibly)? Should he add `overflow: hidden;` as well?

Comment: @zgood i am not a designer, but it should not overflow, if we give a fixed height, it is the same height, irrespective of content, you can add a max-height as well if you want, edited code to reflect changes

Comment: Well you are incorrect. Setting a `height` or `max-height` does not magically scale all the content contained within that area to fit the height you defined. If I define a `div` with 100px height or max-height and stick a 400px tall image in that `div` it will not shrink that image or text to 100px tall. You have to define how the overflow is handled... which if not specified is `overflow: visible;`. See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6LjhdLgc/) which illustrates this with overflowing text.

Comment: @zgood while you can't scale text as simply, you surely can scale images, i have updated the answer accordingly